# Unable to reset blender guru file?

Tags: interface, geometry-nodes

I was able to open and render
[Blender guru gumdrop.blend](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbkN1UnlCWFV4U1hMMEx4S1hLUEVYNk9RTGVVQXxBQ3Jtc0traThXdDA1RWJDay1QVVc1V05oMTc3MHUtQ0UwMU5ETkVCcWZiWTVEUlZyck9NMWpXSUxIR1d0UmR3VmRTN1cwZmJUZnpqZVNTYWxyUTM2bkZObmVXdExLUlVvSDNBWklpekRfVm5DdXpHcl8wemEzVQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fezs3ac34a26aa3f5ce6650303da779cb7c9b.s3.amazonaws.com%2FBlenderGuru_Gumdrop.blend) once. All good.

Suddenly the geometry nodes disappeared on the the drops in the background.

No problem, just download it again. Problem remains.

Ok, just restart the machine, reset blender to default and download again. Problem remains.

I have not the slightest idea what's happening here, do you?

[image: screenshot]

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw9d7piY-Ys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scene looks like the screenshot to me. Only the gumdrop in the front has sugar on top because **the *Geometry Nodes* modifier is disabled in viewport for the other three gumdrops**.

To have them all sugar coated, select the gumdrop object, to go the modifiers tab, and enable the modifier by clicking the "monitor" icon right next to the modifier's name. Repeat the step for the other two gumdrops. That's it.

Comment: Irrelevant here, but perhaps interesting: You can also select all objects and hold alt while clicking the monitor icon which will enable the modifier for all objects.